# How to use Listbox in wp7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, listbox

I have one listbox control in my xaml par.My code for listbox is

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2" Name="ScrollGrid" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="Auto" Width="450" Margin="0,100,0,0" >
    <ListBox x:Name="TransactionList" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0"  Width="400" Height="Auto">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,-10,0,0" Height="120" Width="400" MouseLeftButtonUp="StackPanel_MouseLeftButtonUp">

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Height="80" Width="300" Margin="0,0,20,0">
                        <TextBlock Height="Auto" Margin="20,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="vodafone vas" FontSize="30" Foreground="Gray" Name="tbCitynameFavorite"  />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"  Height="60" Width="60" Margin="0,0,0,30">
                        <Image Name="imgfevdlt" Width="50" Height="40"  VerticalAlignment="Center" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Source="/VodafoneAugmentedReality;component/Images/ArrowMoreSmall.png" />

                    </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Height="10" Width="350" Margin="-360,60,0,0">
                <Image Source="/VodafoneAugmentedReality;component/Images/SaperaterLine.png" Width="350" />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</ScrollViewer>
```

When i run application this will not display any data

But when i comment out this two tag than it will run perfectly

```
 <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
```

Here i have only static value so it will ok but when i have multiple value than it will create problem
So plase help me i can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to set up a class (say ListBoxItem ) which contains all the properties of your DataTemplate members values

And then define a List of ListBoxItem 's and set it as the ItemSource of your ListBox

Example code

```
public class ListBoxItem
{
   public string CityNameFavorite { set; get; }
   // Other required properties follows here
}

List<ListBoxItem> listBoxItems = new List<ListBoxItem>();
listBoxItems.Add(new ListBoxItem() { CityNameFavorite = "Vodafone vas" });
//Add as many items you need


TransactionList.ItemsSource = listBoxItems;
```

This is just an overview of how it can be achieved, improvise based on your needs